# При клике на на другую область документа скрывать input на JS, без Jquery

Tags: javascript

Есть иконка поиска в шапке. При клике на иконку справа выезжает сама форма поиска. Я сделал так чтобы при нажатии на ESC форма скрывалась.
Мне нужно добавить JS код, без Jquery, чтобы форма скрывалась при нажатии на любую другую область. 
Вот код https://jsfiddle.net/DumanTorbayev/92rn6zf5/2/

```js
var searchButton = document.querySelector('.searchOpen-btn');
var searchField = document.querySelector('.mobile-search');

searchButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  searchField.classList.toggle('mobile-search-show');
  searchButton.style.display = 'none'
})

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode === 27) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    if (searchField.classList.contains("mobile-search-show")) {
      searchField.classList.remove("mobile-search-show");
      searchButton.style.display = 'flex'
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.mobile-header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1050px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  box-shadow: 0 -3px 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.58);
}

.mobile-header .logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mobile-header .logo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

.toggle-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.searchOpen-btn {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #619f67;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.mobile-cart {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.mobile-cart img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}

.mobile-search {
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  height: 37px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.mobile-search-show {
  visibility: visible;
  animation: smoothSearhInput .7s;
}

@keyframes smoothSearhInput {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(800px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.mobile-search-field {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.mobile-search-btn {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mobile-search-btn img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

.mobile-toggle {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #7aad7f;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 7px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -8px);
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img class="logo__img" src="img/logo.png" alt="Go Pro Plumbing">
  </div>
  <div class="toggle-wrap">
    <form action="#" method="GET" class="mobile-search">
      <input type="text" class="mobile-search-field" placeholder="Что ищите?">
      <button class="mobile-search-btn"><img src="img/search-icon.svg" alt="Поиск"></button>
    </form>
    <a class="searchOpen-btn" href="#">Поиск</a>
    <a class="mobile-cart" href="cart.html">Корзина</a>
    <div class="mobile-toggle">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, можно сделать так:

```
window.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
  var searchButton = document.querySelector('.searchOpen-btn');
  var searchField = document.querySelector('.mobile-search');
  var f = document.querySelector('.mobile-search-field'); // Поле для поиска

  if (f !== e.target) // если клик был не по нашему полю
  { 
    if (searchField.classList.contains("mobile-search-show")) 
    {
      searchField.classList.remove("mobile-search-show");
      searchButton.style.display = 'flex';
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Comment: Ну и почему `mouseup`?

Answer (score 1):

Стили и разметка не менялись.
А называть форму полем - извращение.

```js
~function () {
  var searchButton = document.querySelector('.searchOpen-btn');
  var searchForm = document.querySelector('.mobile-search');

  searchButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    searchForm.classList.toggle('mobile-search-show');
    searchButton.style.display = 'none'

    window.addEventListener('click', function handler(e) {
      if (!searchForm.contains(e.target)) {
        hide()
        window.removeEventListener('click', handler, true)
      }
    }, true)
    
    
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function handler(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 27) {
        e.preventDefault()
        hide()
        window.removeEventListener('keydown', handler)
      }
    });
  })

  function hide() {
    if (searchForm.classList.contains("mobile-search-show")) {
      searchForm.classList.remove("mobile-search-show");
      searchButton.style.display = 'flex'
    }
  }
}()
```

```css
.mobile-header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1050px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  box-shadow: 0 -3px 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.58);
}

.mobile-header .logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mobile-header .logo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

.toggle-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.searchOpen-btn {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #619f67;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.mobile-cart {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.mobile-cart img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}

.mobile-search {
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  height: 37px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.mobile-search-show {
  visibility: visible;
  animation: smoothSearhInput .7s;
}

@keyframes smoothSearhInput {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(800px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.mobile-search-field {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.mobile-search-btn {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mobile-search-btn img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

.mobile-toggle {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #7aad7f;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 7px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -8px);
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img class="logo__img" src="img/logo.png" alt="Go Pro Plumbing">
  </div>
  <div class="toggle-wrap">
    <form action="#" method="GET" class="mobile-search">
      <input type="text" class="mobile-search-field" placeholder="Что ищите?">
      <button class="mobile-search-btn"><img src="img/search-icon.svg" alt="Поиск"></button>
    </form>
    <a class="searchOpen-btn" href="#">Поиск</a>
    <a class="mobile-cart" href="cart.html">Корзина</a>
    <div class="mobile-toggle">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Я для таких вещей обычно добавляю отдельный див, прозрачный, который появляется по событию. А по клику по нему происходит то, что должно происходить.

```js
var searchButton = document.querySelector('.searchOpen-btn');
var searchField = document.querySelector('.mobile-search');
var wrap = document.querySelector('.wrap');

wrap.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (searchField.classList.contains("mobile-search-show")) {
      searchField.classList.remove("mobile-search-show");
      searchButton.style.display = 'flex'
    }
   wrap.classList.remove('wrap-active');
})

searchButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
  searchField.classList.toggle('mobile-search-show');
  searchButton.style.display = 'none'
  wrap.classList.add('wrap-active');
})

window.addEventListener("keydown", function (evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode === 27) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    if (searchField.classList.contains("mobile-search-show")) {
      searchField.classList.remove("mobile-search-show");
      searchButton.style.display = 'flex'
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
  display: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.wrap-active {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.mobile-header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1050px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  box-shadow: 0 -3px 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.58);
}

.mobile-header .logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mobile-header .logo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

.toggle-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.searchOpen-btn {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #619f67;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.mobile-cart {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.mobile-cart img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}

.mobile-search {
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  height: 37px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.mobile-search-show {
  visibility: visible;
  animation: smoothSearhInput .7s;
}

@keyframes smoothSearhInput{
  0% {transform: translateX(800px);}
  100% {transform: translateY(0);}
}

.mobile-search-field {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.mobile-search-btn {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mobile-search-btn img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

.mobile-toggle {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #7aad7f;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 7px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -8px);
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-header">
      <div class="wrap"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <img class="logo__img" src="img/logo.png" alt="Go Pro Plumbing">
      </div>
      <div class="toggle-wrap">
        <form action="#" method="GET" class="mobile-search">
          <input type="text" class="mobile-search-field" placeholder="Что ищите?">
          <button class="mobile-search-btn"><img src="img/search-icon.svg" alt="Поиск"></button>
        </form>
        <a class="searchOpen-btn" href="#">Поиск</a>
        <a class="mobile-cart" href="cart.html">Корзина</a>
        <div class="mobile-toggle">
          <div class="bar1"></div>
          <div class="bar2"></div>
          <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но такой вариант не подходит)